# Timer Start button

Tags: javascript, button, timer

Hi I'm making a game which involves a count down timer. I want the game to start when the timer button is clicked however at the moment my timer just begins on its own. I have looked at a few different questions already answered however they haven't worked for me. any suggestions?

```
     var seconds = 60;
     function secondPassed() {
        var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
           remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
        }
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
        if (seconds == 0) {
          clearInterval(countdownTimer);
          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Times Up!!!";
        } else {
           seconds--;
        }
     }

     var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

Comment: Can you post HTML of your button?

Comment: I don't see any button or any button click handler respectively ... can you add their code?

Comment: Generally speaking you should learn to use a function reference or anonymous functions as the first parameter to `setInterval` or `setTimeout` rather than strings that need to be evaluated: `var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your setInterval to the button's click listener:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('BUTTON_ID');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/q10z1h9d/)

Answer (score 2):

I guess  you are calling `countdownTimer` on button click, if so, you have to wrap `setInterval` inside a function.

```
var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000); //Without the wrapper it simply executes, when JS reaches this line
```

should be

```
var countdownTimer = function(){setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);}
```